# .scaleAspectFit - filling the blanks with black color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, swift4

I have UIImages that I show in a UIImageView. The UIImageView has the

```
contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

property. The UIImages show just fine on the UIImageView, but I want to edit the UIImages so that they don't have any blank (transparent) space, and instead fill the blank spaces with a black color, and I want it to do this dynamically, depending on the end-users screen size.

Example:

[image]

[image]

What I want to do is replace the areas I've drawn in, with a black color, and save it as an UIImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set backgroundcolor for the uiimageview

Answer (score 1):

Set the background Color of the `imageView` to black

**Using imageView outlet**

```
self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

**Using IB**

[image: Using IB]

Answer (score 1):

Set black color for imageview as well as set frame equal to frame of main view.

```
self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

For AutoRisize:

```
self.imageView.frame = self.view.frame
```

For AutoLayout: 

Set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints with main view (`self.view`)